# Is it possible to put a relationship matrix in a template doc?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to include a graphical representation of a given relationship matrix (e.g. attached figure) in a document template.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but you only get an image that is useless in most cases

Comment: if that image is updated with the current relationships, then I think its fine

Comment: It is up to date (I think) but in all but the most trivial cases it is way to small to be readable, and ugly as well. I usually make an SQL fragment with a table that contains the data we need (in a readable and searchable format)

Comment: I'll try that approach, but nonetheless, could you please point me to how I can insert the image? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the relationship matrix by selecting the section `package > relationship matrix >` and adding `{Matrix.Image}`

[image]

This is however not recommended. In all but the most trivial cases this will result in an unreadable relationship matrix. It looks ugly and is useless.

[image]

A better idea is to create an SQL fragment and put the required info into a table. It isn't quite the same as a matrix, as you you only have a fixed number of columns, but you can at least convey the information in a readable (and searchable) way that looks professional.